# How to analysis the stability of these ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1. Study whether the null solution of the system:
   $$\begin{cases}
    \frac{dx_1}{dt}=x_2(t)\\
    \frac{dx_2}{dt}=-w(t)^2 x_1(t)\\
    \end{cases}
   $$
   is Lyapunov stable, where
   $$ w(t)=
    \begin{cases} 0.4 & \text{for } 2k\pi \leq t < (2k + 1)\pi\\
    0.6 & \text{for } (2k-1)\pi \leq t < 2k\pi
    \end{cases}
   $$
2. Carry out the stability analysis of
   $$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}+1-\cos(x(t))=0$$

Comment: I tried to solve the problem 1 by solve it recursively. but it turned out to be quit complicate.  And, to the No.2 I've found a solution now. Thank you for your attention.